# Reactstrap: Carousel Caption doesn't show up on mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile, reactstrap

I'm having an issue in which my CarouselCaption made via Reactstrap doesn't show up on my phone. After some research, it looks like this is because of the classes `d-none d-md-block`. How do I fix this issue using the Reactstrap module?